# JavaFX code to set RIGHT alignment to few Table Columns

Tags: javafx, tableview

I've populated TableView as follow Dynamically.

[image]

I want data in last 6 columns to be RIGHT aligned. 
How can I set alignment of specific columns dynamically?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically"?

Comment: @James_D using code instead of Scene Builder.... In other words, "At a run time"

Comment: Use a cell factory and set the alignment for the cell. See, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34917983/tableview-column-data-set-to-2-decimal-places (since these look like currency values, the formatting in that question might be useful too)