# Can't properly display data in tableView in JavaFX

Tags: database, hibernate, javafx, tableview

I was trying to add data to my tableView in my JavaFX app. I am using hibernate to do operations on my Database. I used a query to get all the orders and store each order in an object and added the object to the observable list of the tableView. I created the orders class and mapped it to my database. This is the class of the orders:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class orders implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "order_id")
    private int order_id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "item_id")
    @ManyToOne
    @NotNull
    private items item_id;

    @Column(name = "quantity")
    @NotNull
    private int quantity;

    @Column(name = "price_per_unit")
    @NotNull
    private double price_per_unit;

    @Column(name = "total_price")
    @NotNull
    private double total_price;

    @Column(name = "order_date")
    @NotNull
    private Date order_date;

    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    @ManyToOne
    @NotNull
    private users user_id;

    public orders() {
    }

    public orders(int order_id, items item_id, int quantity, double price_per_unit, double total_price, Date order_date, users user_id) {
        this.order_id = order_id;
        this.item_id = item_id;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.price_per_unit = price_per_unit;
        this.total_price = total_price;
        this.order_date = order_date;
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }

    public int getOrder_id() {
        return order_id;
    }

    public void setOrder_id(int order_id) {
        this.order_id = order_id;
    }

    public items getItem_id() {
        return item_id;
    }

    public void setItem_id(items item_id) {
        this.item_id = item_id;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public double getPrice_per_unit() {
        return price_per_unit;
    }

    public void setPrice_per_unit(double price_per_unit) {
        this.price_per_unit = price_per_unit;
    }

    public double getTotal_price() {
        return total_price;
    }

    public void setTotal_price(double total_price) {
        this.total_price = total_price;
    }

    public Date getOrder_date() {
        return order_date;
    }

    public void setOrder_date(Date order_date) {
        this.order_date = order_date;
    }

    public users getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public void setUser_id(users user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }



}
```

And the below code is the code of the view in which I have the tableView that loads the orders and displays the orders from the database:

```
public class OrdersPageController implements Initializable {
    private Main app;
    private Session session;
    private Transaction transaction = null;

    @FXML
    private TableView<orders> table;

    public void setApp(Main app) {
        this.app = app;
    }



    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        //Fill the table view
        getOrders();
    }  


    public void goBack(ActionEvent event){
        session.close();
        transaction = null;
        app.goToHomePage();
    }

    public void processLogout(ActionEvent event){
        session.close();
        transaction = null;
        app.userLogout();
    }

    public void addOrder(ActionEvent event){
        session.close();
        transaction = null;
        app.addOrdersPage();
    }

    public void deleteOrder(ActionEvent event){
        session.close();
        transaction = null;
        app.closeOrdersPage();
    }

    public void getOrders(){

        try{

            String hql = "FROM orders";
            Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
            List<orders> list = query.getResultList();

            for (orders o : list) {
                //Create an order object
                orders order = new orders();
                order.setOrder_id(o.getOrder_id());
                order.setItem_id(o.getItem_id());
                order.setPrice_per_unit(o.getPrice_per_unit());
                order.setQuantity(o.getQuantity());
                order.setOrder_date(o.getOrder_date());
                order.setTotal_price(o.getTotal_price());
                order.setUser_id(o.getUser_id());

                //Create an observable list for the table
                ObservableList<orders> tableList = table.getItems();
                //Add the order object to the list
                tableList.add(order);
                //Set the created list to the table to show data
                table.setItems(tableList);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        finally{
            session.close();
        }

    }

}
```

Note that the getOrders method is the method that gets the orders from the database and sets the observable list of the tableView.

I am having problem displaying the item_id and the user_id of the order. I think the problem is that they both are objects of type items and users respectively and the table displays the address of the objects. Instead I want to display the numbers of the ids of the item ordered and the user that made the order. If you know what I can do to fix my problem please share it with me.

Comment: Use a cell factory to generate cells that display the objects as you want. [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34917983/tableview-column-data-set-to-2-decimal-places) shows how to format a number, but you can use the same technique to set the text in the table cell to any value you need which you get from the data for that cell.

Comment: Slightly off-topic; please use [proper java naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java) - it will enable the code formatter to highlight your code correctly (e.g. class names), make it easier for Java programmers to read, and (since I'm guessing you're using `PropertyValueFactory`s for your cell value factories) it will be less buggy when used in libraries like JavaFX.

Answer (score 1):

Add `cellFactory`s to the relevant columns. You haven't shown the FXML in the question, so I don't know the names you assigned to the appropriate `TableColumn` instances, but you can do something like this:

```
public class OrdersPageController implements Initializable {

    // ...

    @FXML
    private TableView<orders> table;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<orders, users> userColumn ;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        userColumn.setCellFactory(tc -> new TableCell<>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(users user, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(user, empty);
                if (empty || user == null) {
                    setText("");
                } else {
                    String text = /* anything you need based on user */
                    setText(text);
                }
            }
        });

        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        //Fill the table view
        getOrders();
    }  
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Just override `toString` method in `users` and `items`  Classes:

Example: in your `users` Class ->

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return user_id.toString();
}
```

As James_D stated, have a look on java conventions. Java Classes should be always be with Capital Letter.

Comment: This is extremely bad advice. You might need the `toString()` method for other purposes (particularly for debugging) that have nothing to do with how you want the data displayed in the UI.

Comment: I think it is fairly the most simple solution for his code. Too bad you just downvoted it! If we are talking what is good and what is not, than it does not make sense at all to have variable called `user_id` which is from type `users`

Comment: You destroy the purpose of separating the data from the UI if you design methods in the model class (the `toString()` method) to be specific to how the UI is supposed to display the data. Downvoting isn't personal, I'm just trying to prevent future users from using sub-optimal solutions.

Comment: it's plain wrong to override tostring for application reasons, just as @James_D already noted: simply think of visualizing a particular object in different views with different requirements ..